# Selenium RC just run the first case in the suite

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I'm trying to run an html testSuite with Selenium RC. 
The browser starts, the first test runs, but nothing else. Selenium never start running the second test in my suite. Couldn't find anything related in Selenium's RC docs nor internet (except a forum's post without answer).
Could anyone help me? What could I be doing wrong?

If I run the same testsuite using Selenium IDE for firefox it runs perfectly. If I manually run the second testcase in the suite after seleniumRc launching the browser, it runs ok - by running manually I mean clicking in the second row in the left frame of the selenium test page and click in "Run the selected test".

That's the command line I'm using:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlsuite *chrome http://localhost:8088/ /home/devel/Dev/tests/TS_5.1.2 /home/devel/Dev/tests/log.html
```

Apreciate your help!
Fernando

Answer (score 3):

Add ".html" extension to the test suite file and each test case file (else suite will not run past the first test case)

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#html-suite), the command line format is:

> java -jar selenium-server.jar
>   -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com"
>   "c:\absolute\path\to\my\HTMLSuite.html"
>   "c:\absolute\path\to\my\results.html"

which has some subtle differences to yours e.g. capital S in htmlSuite, quotes around everything and the test suite has a html suffix.

Have you tried this with another browser?

Just to confirm you are running an HTML Selenese suite, not a single test?

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I've changed my htmlsuite to htmlSuite and added the quotes to the parameters... still getting the same behaviour... And tried with another browser

Answer (score 1):

If your test case files do not have the html extension you will experience this issue.  Change the extensions on your test cases and make sure your test suite file is pointing to the newly named files.